Первичный пароль postgres
На Ubuntu установил Postgres, Dbeaver.
Пытаюсь создать локальную БД, но требуется ввести пароль от пользователя postgres.
До этого на Windows установливал Postgres и там предлагалось ввести пароль при становке, а здесь ничего такого...
Может кто знает какой пароль устанавливается изначально? Или как поступить в данной ситуации?
Спасибо!

https://stackoverflow.com/q/12720967

спасибо! помогло))

Пакеты ubuntu намеренно не устанавливают вообще никакой дефолтный пароль и тем самым запрещают авторизацию по паролю.
Доступ к суперпользователю СУБД осуществляется методом peer, то есть проверяется авторизация пользователя операционной системы. Начальную настройку предполагается выполнять через sudo от имени postgres пользователя системы.
sudo -u postgres psql

затем уже по усмотрению администратора перенастроить pg_hba, создать пользователей с паролями и так далее.
